# Replace Twilio Flex Logo

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I am looking to replace the flex logo at the top of our instance with our own logo, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this via a plugin.

Is this possible and how do you do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Flex UI documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/ui-configuration-customization#react-defaultprop) you can change default properties for components using React `defaultprops` API programmatically:

```
componentProps: { [Component Name]: { [Prop Name]: [PropValue] } }
```

Example:

```
flex.MainHeader
  .defaultProps
  .logoUrl = "https://static0.twilio.com/marketing/bundles/archetype.alpha/img/logo-wordmark--red.svg";
```

In addition you can find all the configurable components and their defaultProps [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/ui-configuration-customization#flex-agent-and-supervisor-ui)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Well, this is a bit embarrassing, I must have gone blind from looking at them so much, thanks a lot.